# Not able to delete existing component

Tags: sitecore-client

I am facing one issue , I have added breadcrumb in content container that is in partial design. Most of the page is using that content container to add the component.

The components which are added there are showing correctly on the page. However, I am not able to delete the component.

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error when you delete the component or it's not showing the delete option?

Comment: @Nisha Ensure that the component and the placeholder are editable.

Comment: @sumit bhatia it is showing the delete button but It is disabled

Comment: @Ramesh kumar yes both are editable.

Comment: @Nisha and you trying to delete this from partial design right?

Comment: No , from the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete a component that is added to a partial design unless you edit the partial design directly.

You are trying to delete the component while on the page that uses the partial design, this is not possible.

This is expected behavior, the presentation details are stored on the Partial Design item, not on the page level. At runtime, the presentation is merged with the page's presentation (Shared/Final Layout) and rendered. If you want to be able to delete the breadcrumb on specific pages, you need to add the breadcrumb component to the pages directly, maybe with page branches vs using a partial design.

For reference see the documentation on changing a partial design: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/101/sitecore-experience-accelerator/create-and-change-a-partial-design.html